# How-To get root directory of given path in bash?

Tags: bash, path, directory, dirname

My script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    PATH=/home/user/example/foo/bar
    mkdir -p /tmp/backup$PATH
```

And now I want to get first folder of "$PATH": /home/

```
    cd /tmp/backup
    rm -rf ./home/
    cd - > /dev/null
```

How can I always detect the first folder like the example above? "dirname $PATH" just returns "/home/user/example/foo/".

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
    #/usr/bin/env bash
    DIRECTORY="/home/user/example/foo/bar"
    BASE_DIRECTORY=$(echo "$DIRECTORY" | cut -d "/" -f2)
    echo "#$BASE_DIRECTORY#";
```

This returns always the first directory. In this example it would return following:

```
    #home#
```

Thanks to @condorwasabi for his idea with awk! :)

Comment: If your path is relative and looks like this: `dir1/in/dir2` then you should target the field `-f1` instead of `-f2`

Answer (score 7):

If `PATH` always has an absolute form you can do tricks like

```
ROOT=${PATH#/} ROOT=/${ROOT%%/*}
```

Or

```
IFS=/ read -ra T <<< "$PATH"
ROOT=/${T[1]}
```

However I should also add to that that it's better to use other variables and not to use `PATH` as it would alter your search directories for binary files, unless you really intend to.

Also you can opt to convert your path to absolute form through `readlink -f` or `readlink -m`:

```
ABS=$(readlink -m "$PATH")
```

You can also refer to my function [getabspath](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/konsolebox-210384/getting-absolute-paths-of-unix-directories-and-filenames-in-shell-scripts-3956/).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this. o.O But thank you.

Comment: Well too bad. Good luck :)

Comment: The `readlink` is good... unless the path is referring to something non-local (ie: building a command that will be run on another server over ssh).

Answer (score 7):

You can try this awk command:

```
 basedirectory=$(echo "$PATH" | awk -F "/" '{print $2}')
```

At this point `basedirectory` will be the string *home*
Then you write:

```
rm -rf ./"$basedirectory"/
```

Comment: This looks good, but it does not work. $basedirectory is always empty. But thanks! :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Anyway you were right, I just edited the script. I don't know why I wrote `{print $1}`, I also tested it before posting it. Now it should work.

Comment: This also works to get the nth directory along a path e.g. `basedirectory=$(echo "$PATH" | awk -F "/" '{print $3}')`

Comment: replace $2 with $n where n is the nth directory location after first '/' in the path

Answer (score 4):

To get the first directory component of VAR:

```
echo ${VAR%${VAR#/*/}}
```

So, if `VAR="/path/to/foo"`, this returns `/path/`.

Explanation:

`${VAR#X}` strips off the prefix `X` and returns the remainder. So if `VAR=/path/to/foo`, then `/*/` matches the prefix `/path/` and the expression returns the suffix `to/foo`.

`${VAR%X}` strips off the suffix `X`. By inserting the output of `${VAR#X}`, it strips off the suffix and returns the prefix.

If you can guarantee that your paths are well formed this is a convenient method. It won't work well for some paths, such as `//path/to/foo` or `path/to/foo`, but you can handle such cases by breaking down the strings further.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first firectory:

```
path=/home/user/example/foo/bar
mkdir -p "/tmp/backup$path"
cd /tmp/backup
arr=( */ )
echo "${arr[0]}"
```

**PS: Never use PATH variable in your script as it will overrider default PATH and you script won't be able to execute many system utilities**

**EDIT:** Probably this should work for you:

```
IFS=/ && set -- $path; echo "$2"
home
```

Comment: I think, the user wants to extract `home` out of it.

Comment: Hmm `How can I always detect the first folder like the example above` is not very clear. I interpreted it as if OP is trying to get first directory from `/tmp/backup` path.

Comment: I started the comment with intention of thanking you & +1 for your warning about `PATH` variable. :) Then realized that the answer perhaps does not satisfy OP's requirement.

Comment: Hmm probably konsolebox interpreted it right in that case

Comment: From the question: `And now I want to get first folder of "$PATH": /home/`

Comment: Thanks for helping, but your solution is a bit confusing. I found another one. :)

Comment: arr=( /* ). echo just returns the first index of the array, or?

Comment: It is actually `arr=( */ )` which populates `arr` array with all the directories in current path.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash:

```
DIR="/home/user/example/foo/bar"
[[ "$DIR" =~ ^[/][^/]+ ]] && printf "$BASH_REMATCH"
```

Easy to tweak the regex.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname)...

```sh
#/usr/bin/env bash
DIRECTORY="/home/user/example/foo/bar"
BASE_DIRECTORY=$(dirname "${DIRECTORY}")
echo "#$BASE_DIRECTORY#";
```

Outputs the following...

```
/home/user/example/foo
```

Comment: The solution should output `home` not `/home/user/example/foo`.