# Bash. Delete all folders in path

Tags: linux, bash

I have a path like `/mnt/testfolder1/testfolder2` in a variable, I want to check that each folder is empty and then delete it (testfolder2 then testfolder1). How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [`-p` switch of `rmdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rmdir.html):

> Remove all directories in a pathname. For each dir operand:
>
> 1. The directory entry it names shall be removed.
> 2. If the dir operand includes more than one pathname component, effects equivalent to the following command shall occur: `rmdir -p $(dirname dir)`

```
path='/mnt/testfolder1/testfolder2'
rmdir -p "$path"
```

You can also ignore the `/mnt` prefix with [standard parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68582698/112968):

```
path='/mnt/testfolder1/testfolder2'
cd "${path%{${path#/*/}}" # cd /mnt/
rmdir -p "${path#/mnt/}"  # rm -p testfolder1/testfolder2
cd -                      # go back to previous directory
```

---

Alternatively, implement the logic yourself:
Try to delete the directory (it will fail if not empty), then strip the last component with each loop iteration:

```
path='/mnt/testfolder1/testfolder2'
while rmdir "$path" 2>/dev/null; do
  path="${path%/*}"
done
```

To stop at `/mnt`:

```
path='/mnt/testfolder1/testfolder2'
while [ "$path" != '/mnt' ] && rmdir "$path" 2>/dev/null; do
  path="${path%/*}"
done
```

---

I want to highlight [umläute's `find` based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76539131/112968) as well, albeit with a slight modification:

```
path='/mnt/testfolder1/testfolder2'
find "${path%${path#/*/*/}}" -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

This will only delete empty directories, starting with the leaf directories. The parameter expansion only keeps the first 2 components of the path (`mnt` and `testfolder1`)

Comment: I don't want to delete /mnt :)

Comment: @Сиволапый is `/mnt` empty? I assume it isn't → it will not be deleted. Also, `/` is usually owned by root, so you cannot delete directories from there.

Comment: /mnt folder maybe empty.

Comment: @Сиволапый is it always `/mnt` or is that part dynamic too? How do you know which directories to delete and which to keep?

Comment: Yes it is always /mnt, dynamic only what comes after /mnt

Answer (score 1):

just delete recursively:

```
rm -rf /mnt/testfolder1
```

as an explanation:

```
$ man rm
[...]
       -f, --force
              ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
[...]
       -r, -R, --recursive
              remove directories and their contents recursively
```

if you only want to delete *empty* folder, you can use:

```
find /tmp/testfolder1 -depth -type d -delete
```

using `man find` to find out what this actually does it left as an exercise to the user.

Comment: My path in variable. How can i transform path /mnt/testfolder1/testfolder2 to /mnt/testfolder1 in bash ?

Comment: I've changed my question a bit so it's clearer.

Comment: `rm -rf` is dangerous (it will delete all files and directories), but the `find` solution is wonderful. (But it must be `find /tmp/testfolder1 -depth -type d -empty -delete`)

Comment: `-depth` is redundant with `-delete`

Comment: knittl: doh! fixed. thx.